# What can I do about my cat pulling down rolls of toilet paper from our bathrooms?

Tags: cats

From time to time, bathroom doors inevitably get left open either by myself or guests, and when that happens, my cat likes to scratch the toilet paper roll until it has pulled all of the toilet paper off and ripped it to shreds, neatly covering the entire bathroom floor in fine white toilet paper flakes.

What can I do about this, short of leaving tacky little signs reminding bathroom users to close the door and not let the cat slip in? I'm interested in toilet training my cat in the future anyway, so any method that involves keeping the cat out of the bathroom is not really viable.

Answer (score 4):

Put a scrunchy on the roll and when you aren't using the roll, slip it on over the top. This isn't permanent, it's just so you're cats don't get the satisfaction that they crave. Provide them with a toy that gives similar stimulus and use the scrunchies for a few month. Then take them off and see what happens. I'd try this simple solution that costs pennies for the whole house before I try anything more expensive or time consuming.

Also, unless you have a weirdly designed TP holder, I don't see how reversing the roll will help. Most of the rolls I've ever seen in a private residence are simply suspended out from the wall and would unroll equally well, whichever way they spin.

Comment: Many TP-holders I know have a lid on top. This lid lets the roll move in one direction much easier than in the other.

Comment: Oh, okay. I just haven't seen a lot of those around here, but I guess that could help in that situation.

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

- Google "cat-proof toilet paper holder". You will find lots of options.
- Hang the toilet paper the other way. It won't be nearly as much fun to unroll, and the cat will probably ignore it.

Comment: One of mine will try either way. But, yeah, "reversing the polarity" sometimes works.

Answer (score 0):

I cant ever leave toilet paper open in plain view, as my cats just love to rip it apart. I solve it by 1) keeping it in the plastic wrapping, and 2) having the 'used' paper roll in a drawer right next to the toilet.
Only problem is that visitors always take a new roll and leave it out :p